# How can I dismiss a full screen image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view with an image and various details.

I want to click on the image and display in full screen.

For now I use a button to display the image and then a segue I go to a UIViewController that displays the image in full screen.

But I want to return to the previous view by swipe down on the image, with an effect as in the app of Facebook, Twitter, Ebay...

I don't want to use dismissViewControllerAnimated because it does not have the same effect.

Thank you!

Comment: you can used this library for animation effect https://github.com/ideaismobile/IDMPhotoBrowser

Comment: If you want to dismiss a view with custom animation, you have to use UIview animations. you can learn some of them from this tutorial link : http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add TapGesture on image view to show and add PenGesture or SwipeGesture to dismiss as per you requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Try tap gesture**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapImageRemover = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(RemoveImageAction:)];
[yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapImageRemover];
}


- (void)RemoveImageAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
     //Hear You Can Put Code For Remove Image Like [yourImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```